# Error while installing bob via pip on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-bob

I am trying to install bob in Ubuntu.

I just followed the method from the bob tutorial, but it didn't work.

Instead, I got the following output:

```
sudo pip install bob

Collecting bob
  Downloading bob-2.6.2.zip (44kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 34kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from bob)
Collecting bob.extension==2.3.9 (from bob)
  Downloading bob.extension-2.3.9.zip (175kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 184kB 19kB/s 
Collecting bob.blitz==2.0.12 (from bob)
  Downloading bob.blitz-2.0.12.zip (50kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 25kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    Installed /tmp/pip-build-vxxn4w/bob.blitz/.eggs/bob.extension-2.3.11-py2.7.egg
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-vxxn4w/bob.blitz/setup.py", line 70, in <module>
        system_include_dirs=system_include_dirs,
      File "/tmp/pip-build-vxxn4w/bob.blitz/.eggs/bob.extension-2.3.11-py2.7.egg/bob/extension/__init__.py", line 375, in __init__
        pkgs = check_packages(packages)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-vxxn4w/bob.blitz/.eggs/bob.extension-2.3.11-py2.7.egg/bob/extension/__init__.py", line 64, in check_packages
        p = pkgconfig(splitreq[0])
      File "/tmp/pip-build-vxxn4w/bob.blitz/.eggs/bob.extension-2.3.11-py2.7.egg/bob/extension/pkgconfig.py", line 131, in __init__
        raise RuntimeError("pkg-config package `%s' was not found" % name)
    RuntimeError: pkg-config package `blitz' was not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-vxxn4w/bob.blitz/
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 7):

You should have libblitz installed in order to install bob

```
sudo apt-get install libblitz0-dev
sudo pip install bob
```